# How to Stop overscroll / bounce in Phonegap IOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am new to phonegap and using latest version of iPad. I want to prevent the whole app from overscrolling. I've read the related questions and added the following to my config.xml

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

which has no effect
Have to add cordova.js file? to sort out this problem.
[Vertically Bouncing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNXql.jpg)

[Vertically Bouncing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn0ZR.jpg)

**Update**

config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.ufx.phonegap" version="3.0.0">
  <name>UFX</name>
  <description>UFX</description>
  <author href="ufx.com" email="ufx@gmail.com"></author> 
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*" />  
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
  <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
  <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed" value="fast" /> 
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true">
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/> 
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding following line in your config.xml

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Comment: Bro I have already tried by adding above code too.Still not working.

Comment: Have you added "webviewbounce" along with "DisallowOverscroll"? This solution is working for me. If not, can you add your config.xml?

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using? and Which device and model?

Answer (score 0):

After change the config.xml, Just remove ios platform by using terminal and add ios platform again.

It' s worked for me...